# maximo anywhere adding new view not working

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am trying to add a new view in our application. For time being adding this view as the first page in the app. Created necessary OSLC resources in maximo and also verified that I am able to view the data by hitting the URL (ip,userid,pw removed intentionally).
http://{ipaddress}:7001/maximo/oslc/os/ABS_VERI_POINTS?_lid={maximoadminuser}&_lpwd={maximoadminpw}&oslc.select=*

I have also added the view and the resources in app.xml file but when I am logging in to the application it gives me the following message
"WorkList Record Could Not be Downloaded. If Problem persists, Contact your administrator"
After than it landed up into the view with No data. Upon inspecting the UI in browser I noticed I am getting the following error

*Procedure invocation error. Runtime: Failed to parse JSON string
    
    
    
    Error 404--Not Found
    
    
....
....*

Resource Data in app.xml is as follows

```
    <resource describedBy="http://jazz.net/ns/ism/asset/smarter_physical_infrastructure#ABS_VERI_POINTS" id="resabsVP" name="resabsVP"  providedBy="/oslc/sp/SmarterPhysicalInfrastructure">
        <attributes id="absVPAttrs">
            <attribute describedByProperty="spi:parent" id="vpparent" name="parent"/>   
            <attribute describedByProperty="spi:location" id="vplocation" name="location"/>
            <attribute describedByProperty="spi:assetnum" id="vpassetnum" name="assetnum"/>
            <!-- attribute describedByProperty="spi:abs_verification_pointsid" id="vpabsvpid" name="absvppointsid" -->
            <attribute describedByProperty="spi:taskid" id="vptaskid" name="taskid"/>
            <attribute describedByProperty="spi:description" id="vpdescription" name="description"/>
            <attribute describedByProperty="spi:wonum" id="vpwonum" name="wonum"/>

        </attributes>    
        <queryBases id="absvpqry"> 
            <queryBase id="absvpqry1" name="getabsvp" queryUri="oslc/os/ABS_VERI_POINTS" />
        </queryBases> 
    </resource>
```

View in app.xml as follows

```
<view id="absVPview" label="ABS Verification Points"> 
        <requiredResources id="absVPAttrs11">              
             <requiredResource name="resabsVP" id="resabsVP11">
             <requiredAttribute id="vpdescription1" name="description"/>
             <requiredAttribute id="vpwonum1" name="wonum"/>
             <requiredAttribute id="vpparent1" name="parent"/>
             </requiredResource>                
        </requiredResources>
            <list  id="VP.abs_veri_points_list" resource="resabsVP" >               

                <listItemTemplate id="VP.abs_veri_points_list_listItemTemplate"  layout="InspectionListItem">
                <listtext id="VP.abs_veri_points_list_vpid" resourceAttribute="description" layoutInsertAt="item1"/> 
                <listtext id="VP.abs_veri_points_list_wonum" resourceAttribute="wonum" layoutInsertAt="item2"/>
                <listtext id="VP.abs_veri_points_list_parenttext" resourceAttribute="parent" layoutInsertAt="item3"/>                    
                </listItemTemplate>
            </list>

    </view>
```

Can you please give any clue whats going wrong here

Comment: Sample of OSLC resource data that we can see by hitting the URL( in browser is as follows rdfs:member: [
{
spi:parent: 1001,
spi:location: "1001",
spi:assetnum: "1001",
spi:taskid: 1,
spi:description: "Vesselvpoint01",
spi:wonum: "1004",
rdf:about: "http://192.168.56.101:7001/maximo/oslc/os/ABS_VERI_POINTS/_MjE-",
dcterms:identifier: "21"
},
{
spi:parent: 1001,
spi:location: "1001",
spi:assetnum: "1001",
spi:taskid: 2,
spi:description: "Vesselvpoint02",
spi:wonum: "1004",
rdf:about: "http://192.168.56.101:7001/maximo/oslc/os/ABS_VERI_POINTS/_MjI-",
dcterms:identifier: "22"
},

Answer (score 0):

Can you open a PMR on this with our support? This may be a bug where we're not correctly handling underscores in our OSLC request url to retrieve data.  Also, check the URL that is failing in your javascript console, just to make sure that it's really this resource throwing the 404 exception.  You might check the network tab of the debugger to see that.

Answer (score 0):

@MDutta,
If the issue is in the object/attribute using underscore ("_"), you can fix this by updating the xsd validation file located at ..\Anywhere\lib\codegen\artifac-processor-7.5.2.jar. 
Unzip this file and open the app.xsd located: ..\resource\xsd\app.xsd. Modify the validation 
From:

```
<xs:simpleType name="string">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

To:

~dk